# Select dates based on value of other column

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I have a dataframe containing participant Ids (`'Included.y'` column). For each participant I need to schedule an appointment date from one of three possible dates (`'date'` column). The `'vis'` column shows the preferred order of the date of the appointment (V1 then V2 then V3). However, if the value in the `'ficol'` column is equal to or higher than 60, the appointment cannot be booked on that date.

So, for example, participant 5 in the dataframe below, would get date 2021-11-10 since the ficol value has not reached 60. However, participant 6 would ideally get date 2021-10-05, but since there are already 60 ficols, this is not possible. The next date, 2021-10-06 only has 20 ficols so the appointment can be planned there. Each appointment scheduled on a certain date, adds a value of 2 to the ficol column. This means that if we would have 2 additional appointments on 2021-11-09 (which counts for 4 ficols), the ficol column would reach its limit of 60 ficols and thus not allow for any more appointments.

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  Included.y vis   date       ficol
       <int> <chr> <date>     <chr>
1          5 V1    2021-11-10 NA   
2          5 V2    2021-11-11 NA   
3          5 V3    2021-11-09 56   
4          6 V1    2021-10-05 60   
5          6 V2    2021-10-06 20   
6          6 V3    2021-10-04 60
```

The output for participants 5 and 6 would be:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  Included.y vis   date       ficol
       <dbl> <chr> <date>     <chr>
1          5 V1    2021-11-10 2    
2          6 V2    2021-10-06 22
```

Please see below the dput output of the entire dataframe.

```
structure(list(Included.y = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L), vis = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V1", "V2", "V3", "V2", "V1", "V3", "V1", "V2", "V3", 
"V1", "V2", "V3", "V1", "V2", "V3", "V1", "V2"), date = structure(c(18892, 
18893, 18891, 18934, 18935, 18933, 18841, 18900, 18899, 18941, 
18942, 18940, 18905, 18906, 18904, 18912, 18913, 18911, 18919, 
18920), class = "Date"), ficol = c("36", NA, "60", NA, NA, "36", 
"60", NA, " 8", NA, NA, "56", "60", "20", "60", "56", NA, "60", 
"56", NA)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), na.action = structure(c(`7` = 7L, `9` = 9L, `11` = 11L, 
`29` = 29L, `33` = 33L, `35` = 35L, `39` = 39L, `43` = 43L, `45` = 45L, 
`48` = 48L, `50` = 50L, `52` = 52L, `54` = 54L, `61` = 61L, `63` = 63L, 
`70` = 70L, `72` = 72L, `75` = 75L, `80` = 80L, `86` = 86L, `94` = 94L, 
`96` = 96L, `102` = 102L, `109` = 109L, `111` = 111L, `114` = 114L, 
`117` = 117L, `120` = 120L, `121` = 121L, `123` = 123L, `126` = 126L, 
`128` = 128L, `136` = 136L, `138` = 138L, `145` = 145L, `147` = 147L, 
`159` = 159L, `170` = 170L, `173` = 173L, `176` = 176L, `178` = 178L, 
`180` = 180L, `182` = 182L, `188` = 188L, `193` = 193L, `195` = 195L, 
`199` = 199L, `201` = 201L, `207` = 207L, `217` = 217L, `219` = 219L, 
`227` = 227L, `231` = 231L, `233` = 233L, `235` = 235L, `237` = 237L, 
`240` = 240L, `245` = 245L, `251` = 251L, `262` = 262L, `264` = 264L, 
`267` = 267L, `280` = 280L, `282` = 282L, `283` = 283L, `285` = 285L, 
`287` = 287L, `291` = 291L, `293` = 293L, `297` = 297L, `298` = 298L, 
`300` = 300L, `301` = 301L, `303` = 303L, `309` = 309L, `311` = 311L, 
`314` = 314L, `317` = 317L, `323` = 323L, `327` = 327L, `333` = 333L, 
`342` = 342L, `345` = 345L, `354` = 354L, `362` = 362L, `364` = 364L, 
`366` = 366L, `367` = 367L, `369` = 369L, `375` = 375L, `376` = 376L, 
`378` = 378L, `380` = 380L, `388` = 388L, `390` = 390L, `393` = 393L, 
`403` = 403L, `405` = 405L, `413` = 413L, `420` = 420L, `435` = 435L, 
`437` = 437L, `443` = 443L, `448` = 448L, `450` = 450L, `458` = 458L, 
`464` = 464L, `466` = 466L, `468` = 468L, `469` = 469L, `471` = 471L, 
`472` = 472L, `474` = 474L, `475` = 475L, `477` = 477L, `482` = 482L, 
`485` = 485L, `489` = 489L, `490` = 490L, `492` = 492L, `494` = 494L, 
`497` = 497L, `522` = 522L, `523` = 523L, `525` = 525L, `528` = 528L, 
`532` = 532L, `534` = 534L, `537` = 537L, `540` = 540L, `543` = 543L, 
`547` = 547L, `549` = 549L, `554` = 554L, `567` = 567L, `574` = 574L, 
`576` = 576L, `579` = 579L, `584` = 584L, `589` = 589L, `591` = 591L, 
`593` = 593L, `596` = 596L, `598` = 598L, `600` = 600L, `603` = 603L, 
`604` = 604L, `606` = 606L, `608` = 608L, `618` = 618L, `634` = 634L, 
`636` = 636L, `639` = 639L, `640` = 640L, `642` = 642L, `646` = 646L, 
`648` = 648L, `650` = 650L, `660` = 660L, `666` = 666L, `669` = 669L, 
`675` = 675L, `678` = 678L, `681` = 681L, `683` = 683L, `693` = 693L, 
`695` = 695L, `700` = 700L, `702` = 702L, `708` = 708L, `714` = 714L, 
`716` = 716L, `718` = 718L, `720` = 720L, `723` = 723L, `725` = 725L, 
`727` = 727L, `729` = 729L, `731` = 731L, `752` = 752L, `754` = 754L, 
`756` = 756L, `759` = 759L, `774` = 774L, `779` = 779L, `782` = 782L, 
`784` = 784L, `786` = 786L, `793` = 793L, `795` = 795L, `803` = 803L, 
`806` = 806L, `808` = 808L, `810` = 810L, `812` = 812L, `820` = 820L, 
`822` = 822L, `828` = 828L, `829` = 829L, `831` = 831L, `833` = 833L, 
`835` = 835L, `837` = 837L, `841` = 841L, `843` = 843L, `845` = 845L, 
`848` = 848L, `852` = 852L, `853` = 853L, `855` = 855L, `860` = 860L, 
`863` = 863L, `865` = 865L, `867` = 867L, `873` = 873L, `874` = 874L, 
`876` = 876L, `879` = 879L, `882` = 882L, `885` = 885L, `889` = 889L, 
`891` = 891L, `893` = 893L, `906` = 906L, `907` = 907L, `909` = 909L, 
`913` = 913L, `915` = 915L, `918` = 918L, `919` = 919L, `921` = 921L, 
`924` = 924L, `926` = 926L, `928` = 928L, `930` = 930L, `934` = 934L, 
`936` = 936L, `941` = 941L, `960` = 960L, `961` = 961L, `963` = 963L, 
`965` = 965L, `983` = 983L, `986` = 986L, `988` = 988L, `990` = 990L, 
`1001` = 1001L, `1007` = 1007L, `1011` = 1011L, `1013` = 1013L, 
`1018` = 1018L, `1020` = 1020L, `1024` = 1024L, `1026` = 1026L, 
`1031` = 1031L, `1034` = 1034L, `1044` = 1044L, `1046` = 1046L, 
`1049` = 1049L, `1053` = 1053L, `1056` = 1056L, `1059` = 1059L, 
`1069` = 1069L, `1071` = 1071L, `1077` = 1077L, `1080` = 1080L, 
`1086` = 1086L, `1093` = 1093L, `1095` = 1095L, `1097` = 1097L, 
`1102` = 1102L, `1104` = 1104L, `1108` = 1108L, `1110` = 1110L, 
`1121` = 1121L, `1125` = 1125L, `1138` = 1138L, `1140` = 1140L, 
`1152` = 1152L, `1154` = 1154L, `1156` = 1156L, `1158` = 1158L, 
`1165` = 1165L, `1167` = 1167L, `1170` = 1170L, `1179` = 1179L, 
`1183` = 1183L, `1185` = 1185L, `1188` = 1188L, `1189` = 1189L, 
`1191` = 1191L, `1192` = 1192L, `1194` = 1194L, `1202` = 1202L, 
`1209` = 1209L, `1213` = 1213L, `1215` = 1215L, `1218` = 1218L, 
`1220` = 1220L, `1229` = 1229L, `1233` = 1233L, `1235` = 1235L, 
`1239` = 1239L, `1240` = 1240L, `1242` = 1242L, `1243` = 1243L, 
`1245` = 1245L, `1246` = 1246L, `1248` = 1248L, `1254` = 1254L, 
`1256` = 1256L, `1262` = 1262L, `1269` = 1269L, `1275` = 1275L, 
`1276` = 1276L, `1278` = 1278L, `1293` = 1293L, `1295` = 1295L, 
`1297` = 1297L, `1299` = 1299L, `1301` = 1301L, `1303` = 1303L, 
`1305` = 1305L, `1307` = 1307L, `1311` = 1311L, `1312` = 1312L, 
`1314` = 1314L, `1315` = 1315L, `1317` = 1317L, `1328` = 1328L, 
`1330` = 1330L, `1332` = 1332L, `1334` = 1334L, `1336` = 1336L, 
`1338` = 1338L, `1341` = 1341L, `1343` = 1343L, `1346` = 1346L, 
`1352` = 1352L, `1356` = 1356L, `1361` = 1361L, `1373` = 1373L, 
`1380` = 1380L, `1381` = 1381L, `1383` = 1383L, `1384` = 1384L, 
`1386` = 1386L, `1388` = 1388L, `1392` = 1392L, `1393` = 1393L, 
`1395` = 1395L, `1398` = 1398L, `1401` = 1401L, `1411` = 1411L, 
`1413` = 1413L, `1414` = 1414L, `1416` = 1416L, `1418` = 1418L, 
`1427` = 1427L, `1433` = 1433L, `1437` = 1437L, `1440` = 1440L, 
`1443` = 1443L, `1444` = 1444L, `1446` = 1446L, `1448` = 1448L, 
`1451` = 1451L, `1464` = 1464L, `1472` = 1472L, `1475` = 1475L, 
`1483` = 1483L, `1485` = 1485L, `1493` = 1493L, `1500` = 1500L, 
`1502` = 1502L, `1504` = 1504L, `1506` = 1506L, `1511` = 1511L, 
`1516` = 1516L, `1518` = 1518L, `1523` = 1523L, `1528` = 1528L, 
`1530` = 1530L, `1539` = 1539L, `1545` = 1545L, `1546` = 1546L, 
`1548` = 1548L, `1550` = 1550L, `1553` = 1553L, `1556` = 1556L, 
`1558` = 1558L, `1560` = 1560L, `1565` = 1565L, `1568` = 1568L, 
`1575` = 1575L, `1576` = 1576L, `1578` = 1578L, `1583` = 1583L, 
`1590` = 1590L, `1596` = 1596L, `1599` = 1599L, `1605` = 1605L, 
`1606` = 1606L, `1608` = 1608L, `1613` = 1613L, `1616` = 1616L, 
`1627` = 1627L, `1629` = 1629L, `1643` = 1643L, `1645` = 1645L, 
`1647` = 1647L, `1653` = 1653L, `1655` = 1655L, `1661` = 1661L, 
`1663` = 1663L, `1665` = 1665L, `1674` = 1674L, `1678` = 1678L, 
`1680` = 1680L, `1685` = 1685L, `1692` = 1692L, `1696` = 1696L, 
`1698` = 1698L, `1702` = 1702L, `1704` = 1704L, `1710` = 1710L, 
`1711` = 1711L, `1713` = 1713L, `1720` = 1720L, `1722` = 1722L, 
`1725` = 1725L, `1726` = 1726L, `1728` = 1728L, `1730` = 1730L, 
`1732` = 1732L, `1734` = 1734L, `1736` = 1736L, `1738` = 1738L, 
`1740` = 1740L, `1743` = 1743L, `1746` = 1746L, `1750` = 1750L, 
`1752` = 1752L, `1759` = 1759L, `1761` = 1761L, `1764` = 1764L, 
`1767` = 1767L, `1768` = 1768L, `1770` = 1770L, `1777` = 1777L, 
`1779` = 1779L, `1785` = 1785L, `1786` = 1786L, `1788` = 1788L, 
`1791` = 1791L, `1792` = 1792L, `1794` = 1794L, `1801` = 1801L, 
`1803` = 1803L, `1805` = 1805L, `1809` = 1809L, `1813` = 1813L, 
`1815` = 1815L, `1817` = 1817L, `1820` = 1820L, `1823` = 1823L, 
`1830` = 1830L, `1843` = 1843L, `1845` = 1845L, `1848` = 1848L, 
`1857` = 1857L, `1860` = 1860L, `1862` = 1862L, `1864` = 1864L, 
`1866` = 1866L, `1867` = 1867L, `1869` = 1869L, `1870` = 1870L, 
`1872` = 1872L, `1875` = 1875L, `1876` = 1876L, `1878` = 1878L, 
`1879` = 1879L, `1881` = 1881L, `1883` = 1883L, `1890` = 1890L, 
`1893` = 1893L, `1901` = 1901L, `1911` = 1911L, `1916` = 1916L, 
`1920` = 1920L, `1924` = 1924L, `1926` = 1926L, `1927` = 1927L, 
`1929` = 1929L, `1935` = 1935L, `1938` = 1938L, `1941` = 1941L, 
`1942` = 1942L, `1944` = 1944L, `1945` = 1945L, `1947` = 1947L, 
`1955` = 1955L, `1960` = 1960L, `1962` = 1962L, `1963` = 1963L, 
`1965` = 1965L, `1968` = 1968L, `1980` = 1980L, `1982` = 1982L, 
`1984` = 1984L, `1986` = 1986L, `1991` = 1991L, `2000` = 2000L, 
`2008` = 2008L, `2010` = 2010L, `2015` = 2015L, `2017` = 2017L, 
`2019` = 2019L, `2022` = 2022L, `2025` = 2025L, `2028` = 2028L, 
`2029` = 2029L, `2031` = 2031L, `2033` = 2033L, `2049` = 2049L, 
`2051` = 2051L, `2053` = 2053L, `2055` = 2055L, `2057` = 2057L, 
`2062` = 2062L, `2064` = 2064L, `2066` = 2066L, `2069` = 2069L, 
`2071` = 2071L, `2073` = 2073L, `2076` = 2076L, `2080` = 2080L, 
`2082` = 2082L, `2084` = 2084L, `2090` = 2090L, `2096` = 2096L, 
`2099` = 2099L, `2101` = 2101L, `2103` = 2103L, `2108` = 2108L, 
`2110` = 2110L, `2112` = 2112L, `2120` = 2120L, `2122` = 2122L, 
`2124` = 2124L, `2125` = 2125L, `2127` = 2127L, `2130` = 2130L, 
`2135` = 2135L, `2143` = 2143L, `2145` = 2145L, `2149` = 2149L, 
`2151` = 2151L, `2154` = 2154L, `2157` = 2157L, `2166` = 2166L, 
`2169` = 2169L, `2171` = 2171L, `2185` = 2185L, `2187` = 2187L, 
`2189` = 2189L, `2192` = 2192L, `2194` = 2194L, `2196` = 2196L, 
`2203` = 2203L, `2205` = 2205L, `2206` = 2206L, `2208` = 2208L, 
`2212` = 2212L, `2214` = 2214L, `2216` = 2216L, `2232` = 2232L, 
`2234` = 2234L, `2238` = 2238L, `2242` = 2242L, `2244` = 2244L, 
`2247` = 2247L, `2250` = 2250L, `2251` = 2251L, `2253` = 2253L, 
`2255` = 2255L, `2258` = 2258L, `2265` = 2265L, `2267` = 2267L, 
`2273` = 2273L, `2277` = 2277L, `2282` = 2282L, `2287` = 2287L, 
`2289` = 2289L, `2290` = 2290L, `2292` = 2292L, `2296` = 2296L, 
`2298` = 2298L, `2299` = 2299L, `2301` = 2301L, `2302` = 2302L, 
`2304` = 2304L, `2305` = 2305L, `2307` = 2307L, `2310` = 2310L, 
`2317` = 2317L, `2319` = 2319L, `2324` = 2324L, `2326` = 2326L, 
`2328` = 2328L, `2334` = 2334L, `2335` = 2335L, `2337` = 2337L, 
`2338` = 2338L, `2340` = 2340L, `2341` = 2341L, `2343` = 2343L, 
`2348` = 2348L, `2352` = 2352L, `2361` = 2361L, `2362` = 2362L, 
`2364` = 2364L, `2365` = 2365L, `2367` = 2367L, `2383` = 2383L, 
`2385` = 2385L, `2390` = 2390L, `2393` = 2393L, `2403` = 2403L, 
`2407` = 2407L, `2409` = 2409L, `2418` = 2418L, `2421` = 2421L, 
`2425` = 2425L, `2427` = 2427L, `2432` = 2432L, `2436` = 2436L, 
`2440` = 2440L, `2442` = 2442L, `2445` = 2445L, `2448` = 2448L, 
`2457` = 2457L, `2460` = 2460L, `2464` = 2464L, `2466` = 2466L, 
`2468` = 2468L, `2470` = 2470L, `2472` = 2472L, `2477` = 2477L, 
`2481` = 2481L, `2494` = 2494L, `2496` = 2496L, `2504` = 2504L, 
`2508` = 2508L, `2514` = 2514L, `2518` = 2518L, `2520` = 2520L, 
`2522` = 2522L, `2532` = 2532L, `2535` = 2535L, `2546` = 2546L, 
`2551` = 2551L, `2553` = 2553L, `2557` = 2557L, `2559` = 2559L, 
`2560` = 2560L, `2562` = 2562L, `2565` = 2565L, `2570` = 2570L, 
`2574` = 2574L, `2575` = 2575L, `2577` = 2577L, `2578` = 2578L, 
`2580` = 2580L, `2582` = 2582L, `2585` = 2585L), class = "omit"))
```

How can we manage this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so in the case where Participant 3 only has a single slot and its full, i.e.
 3 V2 2021-08-02 60
Are they allocated to another date or are they just dropped off?

Comment: In the case of only having dates available that already contain a ficol value of 60, the participant will be dropped off. Thanks for asking!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

I come up with a solution using data.table below. Please let me know if you have any questions.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

dt <- data.table(dt)
dt[, c("date", "ficol") := .(ymd(date), as.numeric(ficol))]

# Sort by ID and visit 
setorder(dt, Included.y, vis)

# Flag open appointment
dt[, open := ifelse(is.na(ficol) | ficol<60, TRUE, FALSE)]

# Select first open appointment and update ficol
out_dt <- dt[open==TRUE, .SD[1], by = c("Included.y")]
out_dt[, ficol := ifelse(is.na(ficol), 2, ficol+2)]
out_dt[, open := NULL]

out_dt

   Included.y vis       date ficol
1:          1  V1 2021-09-22    38
2:          2  V1 2021-11-03     2
3:          4  V1 2021-09-30     2
4:          5  V1 2021-11-10     2
5:          6  V2 2021-10-06    22
6:          7  V1 2021-10-12    58
7:          8  V1 2021-10-19    58
```

Comment: Hi lil_barnacle, your solution above would work well if the dates did not occur more than once.  However, the real dataframe consists of about 900 participants so there will be dates occuring more than once. Each time the date is selected, it would need to count +2 in the ficol time for each time the date is selected, now it only adds +2 one time. In the real dataset, 11 people would get assigned date 2021-08-26 and the ficols started out at NA. So the ficol count after assigning the dates to 11 people would be 22 and now it stays at 2. Is there any way to account for this? Thanks for the help

Comment: Also, a date that would already have 58 ficols to start with should not get more than 1 more participant assigned to it (since then it reaches 60).  With your solution, the cumulated ficol count is not accounted for